# epoll_wait() consume too much CPU

Tags: linux, epoll, strace

my epoll_wait() is consuming too much CPU, a simple strace shows that:

```
    strace -c -f -p 3655
    Process 3655 attached with 5 threads
    ^CProcess 3655 detached
    Process 3656 detached
    Process 3657 detached
    Process 3658 detached
    Process 3659 detached
    % time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
    ------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
     64.43   32.228205      596819        54           epoll_wait
     35.31   17.661939          17   1063312    195547 futex
      0.26    0.131803           0    448140           gettimeofday
      0.00    0.000090           3        27           write
      0.00    0.000050           1        54           epoll_ctl
      0.00    0.000000           0        54        27 read
      0.00    0.000000           0         9           sendmsg
      0.00    0.000000           0        90        54 recvmsg
    ------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
    100.00   50.022087               1511740    195628 total
```

there are just 54 epoll_wait() calls, but usecs/call of epoll_wait() is 596819, why?

Answer (score 3):

In this case the time reported by `strace` is a bit misleading.

[`strace(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) tells us:

> -c Count time, calls, and errors for each system call and report a
>   summary on program exit.  On Linux, this attempts to show system time
>   **(CPU time spent running in the kernel)** independent of wall clock time.

But I suspect what **it's actually counting is just the time from when `epoll_wait` was called until it returned**. This doesn't mean your process was `"running"` in the kernel. It's far more likely it was sleeping, which is natural for `epoll_wait`.

Comment: I'm not very sure how strace count the CPU time, but the process actually did use 130% of the CPU in a 2-core machine.

Comment: @Wenlin.Wu This is interesting. Do you have a minimal program to try it out? `epoll_wait` should just put the process on a wait queue; spending a significant amount of CPU time sounds like a bug.

Comment: indeed, it's my Bind DNS service, and it's a known bug of Bind, see this https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=709205 , I just don't know how this happens.

Comment: @Wenlin.Wu Fascinating bug report. I don't think the conclusion there is that `epoll_wait` is at fault; much more likely is that the following happens:
1. `named` gets into trouble and starts using a lot of CPU
2. You (naturally) `strace` it to find out what it's doing
3. `strace` misleads you with `epoll_wait` times - classic red herring.

I suggest trying something else to measure CPU utilization such as http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html.

Answer (score 0):

I have also met the similar issue. In my case, I passed `int timeout` as 0, which causes `epoll_wait()` return immediately regardless of available event. [epoll_wait doc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_wait.2.html). Therefore, the solution is you should set the `timeout` as non-zero value to indicate either it blocks indefinitely or temporarily. I set it to -1 then everything goes fine.